# Unable to apply a user.module Core patch in Drupal 7.x site using Composer

Tags: composer

I have a patch https://www.drupal.org/files/user_reset_password_privacy-1521996-10.patch,
which is to be applied to user.module using Composer. I have added the URL under `"patches"` as well.

```json
"patches" : {
   "drupal/module" : {
     "string" : "patch_link"
  }
}
```

After running the command composer update drupal/core I am getting:

> Nothing to install or update

Need expert assistance here on where I am going wrong here.

Comment: Not sure about D7, but patches for D8/D9 core modules should be applied with `composer update drupal/core`-- try that instead.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I am updating using the above command but still getting **Nothing to install or update**

Comment: You need to run `composer install` to get the patch applied, not `composer update`. Does your composer.json contain `cweagans/composer-patches` in the `"require"` section? `composer --version` returns you what version? Please post the whole content of your composer.json in your question.

Comment: We need the whole composer.json. Maybe your site isn't even managed by Composer. Just a composer.json exists which isn't even connected to your Drupal at all.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `drupal/core` in the `patches` section of composer.json, not `drupal/module`.

`patches` must be nested under `extra`. I cannot determine from the question as written if that is the case.